# Failing in liquid include if parameter not set

Tags: liquid

Let's say I have an include snippet `foo.html` like so:

```html
<a href="table/{{include.file}}.html">
    <img src="{{include.file}}.svg" alt="{{ include.alt | default: 'Figure' }}">
</a>
```

This should be called like:

```
{% include foo.html file="blah" %}
```

I'd like to fail the liquid run with a diagnostic if the `file="blah"` part is missing (there is no useful default to use).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this this code:

```
 {% include 'foo.html', file:'blah' %}
```